# Use model data on Url.Action attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need to add an attribute to the form tag (Html.BeginForm) and the value of this attribute must be the parameter of the edit action (ID).

How can I do this?

Here is my action code:

```
    //
    // GET: /Panel/Partners/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var repository = new PartnersRepository();

        var data = repository.Find(id);

        return View(data);
    }
```

And here is the code for the form tag:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Partners", 
    FormMethod.Post, 
    new { 
        enctype = "multipart/form-data", 
        id = "partnersForm", 
        data_removelogo = @Url.Action("RemoveLogo", "Partners", new { Area = "Panel", id = Model.ID }) }
        ))
```

The Url.Action from the data_removelogo attribute doesn't work with the Model.ID property.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work with the Model.ID property?  Does it throw an error?  What error?  What does it do? Are you sure you have a matching route?  What value do you expect Model.ID to be?  Are you sure it is what you expect?

Comment: It gives me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." because Model is not a variable, if I use Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ID) it works, but I can't use it this way to add a value to an attribute.

Comment: Hi, if you look at the overloads for beginform, you can see a string, string, routevalues, formmethod, htmlattributes.  I believe you can lay your being form as: BeginForm("Edit", "Partners", new { id = Model.ID}, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype ....}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments it sounds like you are passing a `null` model into your view.  When you try and access any properties on a null reference you're going to get the error you're getting.  You either need to make sure in your controller that you don't pass in a null model, or in your view you're going to need logic to handle a null model, such as checking for null before accessing the id.

Comment: Sorry guys, I've sent an answer to my on question, but somehow it has not been published on StackOverflow.

The error was in my controller postback action, then my Model would always be null.